# How to write a RSpec using httprb/http gem with timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

According to `httprb/http` gem's wiki, there is a way to enable per operation timeouts to handle Timeout like:

```
HTTP.timeout(:per_operation, :write => 2, :connect => 5, :read => 10)
.get "http://example.com"
```

but when I use this chaining method, is there a way to test it in RSpec when request server(or a stub one) is down, and I can receive `HTTP::TimeoutError` ?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In RSpec you can expect to have a timeout like this:

`Net::HTTP.should_receive(:request_get).and_raise(Timeout::Error)`

so if this is true you can skip the test's after this condition.